# Cypress with stripe: elements height not loaded

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, cypress

I'm using cypress since a week, and I succesfully did an integration with the stripe iframe: I've used this code:

in `cypress/support/command.js`

```
Cypress.Commands.add('iframeLoaded', { prevSubject: 'element' }, $iframe => {
  const contentWindow = $iframe.prop('contentWindow')
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (contentWindow && contentWindow.document.readyState === 'complete') {
      resolve(contentWindow)
    } else {
      $iframe.on('load', () => {
        resolve(contentWindow)
      })
    }
  })
})

Cypress.Commands.add('getInDocument', { prevSubject: 'document' }, (document, selector) =>
  Cypress.$(selector, document),
)
```

In `cypress/integration/staging-web/web.test.js`

```
    cy.get('iframe')
      .eq(1)
      .iframeLoaded()
      .its('document')
      .getInDocument('[name="cardnumber"]')
    
      .then($iframe => {
          if ($iframe.is(':visible')) {
              $iframe.type('4242424242424242')
          }
      })
    
  cy.get('iframe')
      .eq(1)
      .iframeLoaded()
      .its('document')
      .getInDocument('[name="exp-date"]')
    
      .then($iframe => {
          if ($iframe.is(':visible')) {
              $iframe.type('1225')
          }
      })
    
  cy.get('iframe')
      .eq(2)
      .iframeLoaded()
      .its('document')
      .getInDocument('[name="cvc"]')
    
          .then($iframe => {
              if ($iframe.is(':visible')) {
                  $iframe.type('123')
              }
          })
    
  cy.get('.mt1 > .relative > .input').type('utente')
```

My problem is that during the page loading, cypress does not wait until stripe fields are fully loaded, and I get an error because happens this (sorry for not-english language, but it's a screenshot):

[image]

Those lines are:

- cardnumber
- expiration date , pin number
- 4th line is card owner

I've tried with `.should('be.visibile')` but it does nothing; plus I've tried with

```
cy.get('iframe')
    .eq(1)
    .iframeLoaded()
    .its('document')
    .getInDocument('[name="cardnumber"]')

    .then($iframe => {
        if ($iframe.is(':visible')) {
            $iframe.type('4242424242424242')
        }
    })
```

but no way, it always gives me an error; in this latter case, it doesn't even give an error, it just goes on without filling the fields and after this it stops because it cant go on in the test.

If I add `cy.wait(800)` before the code in `web.test.js` it works fine, but I don't want to use `wait`, because it's basically wrong (what happens if it loads after 5 seconds?).

is there a way to check that those elements must have an height?
Remember that they are in an `iframe` (sadly).

Comment: Related Cypress Stripe Elements with a solution for 2022. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882883/cypress-12-8-1-not-working-with-stripe-elements-iframe/75883621#75883621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***If I add cy.wait(800) ... it works fine***.

This is because you are not using Cypress commands with auto-retry inside `getInDocument()`.

`Cypress.$(selector)` is jQuery, it just attempts to grab the element, not retry for async loading, and no test failure when not found.

Should use a proper command with retry, like

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getInDocument', { prevSubject: 'document' }, (document, selector) =>
  cy.wrap(document).find(selector)
)
```

or you might need to work from `body`

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getInDocument', { prevSubject: 'document' }, (document, selector) =>
  cy.wrap(document).its('body')
    .find(selector)
    .should('be.visible')
)
```

Without a test system I'm not sure exactly which one is correct syntax, but you get the idea.

---

Also, too many custom commands. You always follow `.iframeLoaded()` with `.its('document')`, so just wrap it all up in `iframeLoaded` custom command.

In fact, `resolve(contentWindow.document.body)` because it's a better point to chain `.find(selector)`.

---

This is my test against the Stripe demo page,

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('iframeLoaded', { prevSubject: 'element' }, $iframe => {
  const contentWindow = $iframe.prop('contentWindow')
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (contentWindow && contentWindow.document.readyState === 'complete') {
      resolve(contentWindow.document.body)
    } else {
      $iframe.on('load', () => {
        resolve(contentWindow.document.body)
      })
    }
  })
})

it('finds card number', () => {

  cy.viewport(1000, 1000)
  cy.visit('https://stripe-payments-demo.appspot.com/')
  cy.get('iframe')
    .should('have.length.gt', 1)  // sometimes 2nd iframe is slow to load
    .eq(1)
    .iframeLoaded()
    .find('input[name="cardnumber"]')
    .should('be.visible')
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I totally ignored the existence of .wrap(), this helps me a lot in understanding cypress =) however, my issue is also that if the page is shown as the screenshot above, I totally don't know why, but it does not load the content anymore; I should do a cy.reload(), but I don't know where to put it :/ I tried with an if, but it should contain something like "if it has tried and it is undefined - or height is less than 5px - , reload the page"

Comment: It looks like there is some animation/transition going on and the element with name "cardnumber" is present but is in pre-transition stage. Just a guess, try adding `.should('be.visible')` to the find. (see above)

Comment: well, when i use `cy.wrap(document).its('body').find(selector).should('be.visible')` , it says `-find [name="cardnumber"] expected <input> to be visible` and `This element <input> is not visible because it has CSS property: opacity: 0` , but if I check the element with chrome tools at the end of the test, the css is set to `1`...I'm getting mad

Comment: I did something terrible, I used `cy.wrap(document).its('body').find(selector)` then launched in main test this: `const ADD_MS = 200
function checkAgainStripe() {
  let waitForMillisecs = 500
  cy.get('.btn').scrollIntoView().should('be.visible').click()
  cy.get('iframe')
    .eq(1)
    .then($elem => {
      cy.wait(waitForMillisecs)
      waitForMillisecs = waitForMillisecs + ADD_MS
      if (!$elem[0] || !$elem[0].offsetHeight || $elem[0].offsetHeight < 19) {
        console.log('entered in if')
        cy.reload()
        return checkAgainStripe()
      }
    })
}`

Comment: please if you can tell me what you think about :)

Comment: I think it's ok to add an explicit wait, it's certainly effective and you only wait a few hundred milliseconds. I don't know why you were unable to overcome the transition problem with `.should()`, I couldn't reproduce it on the Stripe demo page (see my test above).

Comment: Ok, thanks! Yeah, it's REALLY strange, maybe it's something in the webpage realization (not made by me, i'm a tester) that freezes everything! You know, I'm pretty new with cypress, so I thought I did some mistake somewhere...but...seems not :) Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

@Nanker Phelge by the way I updated my function in this way, I posted it here because there was no space in comments:

UPDATE: I put `waitForMillisecs` inside the function -_- it HAVE TO stay outside! Correction made.

```
const ADD_MS = 200
const STACK_LIMIT = 15
let stackNumber = 0
let waitForMillisecs = 500

    function checkAgainStripe() {  
      stackNumber++
    
      if (stackNumber >= STACK_LIMIT) {
        throw new Error('Error: too many tries on Stripe iframe. Limit reached is', STACK_LIMIT)
      }
    
      cy.get('.btn').scrollIntoView().should('be.visible').click()
      cy.get('iframe')
        .eq(1)
        .then($elem => {
          //console.log($elem[0].offsetHeight)
          //console.log($elem[0])
          cy.log('now wait for ' + waitForMillisecs + '; stack number is ' + stackNumber)
          cy.wait(waitForMillisecs)
          waitForMillisecs = waitForMillisecs + ADD_MS
          if (!$elem[0] || !$elem[0].offsetHeight || $elem[0].offsetHeight < 19) {
            console.log('entered in if')
            cy.reload()
            return checkAgainStripe()
          }
        })
    }
```