# How to allow cross-origin iframe access for WebKit/Playwright with Cypress?

Tags: node.js, cypress, webkit, cross-domain, playwright

do you by any chance know if there is an equivalent to chromeWebSecurity: false for WebKit/Playwright to be able to access a cross-origin iframe (Stripe credit card)?

I use this solution to access iframes with Cypress:
[Cypress with stripe: elements height not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902643/cypress-with-stripe-elements-height-not-loaded)

But since it's a Stripe iframe, it only works if I set the chromeWebSecurity option to false. This option only works with Chrome, Edge and Electron browsers but does not work with WebKit and Firefox.

When I try to access the Stripe iframe for credit cards with WebKit, I get the following error:

SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin “https://www.test.com” from accessing a cross-origin frame. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

When I try with Firefox, I get the following error:

Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object