# Cypress 12.14 can not get Iframe contentDocument for Stripe after some changes

Tags: cypress

A bit of background, the function works fine until a certain changes regarding Stripe.

From what the Dev Team said, they changed the Stripe keys, because they're using a new account for Stripe.

I used the function from this post
[Cypress 12.8.1 not working with Stripe Elements iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882883/cypress-12-8-1-not-working-with-stripe-elements-iframe)

This is the function and how I used it

```
function getStripeField({iframeSelector, fieldSelector}, attempts = 0) {
            if (attempts > 50) throw new Error('too many attempts')
            return cy.get(iframeSelector, {timeout:10_000, log:false})
                .eq(0, {log:true})
                .its('0.contentDocument', {log:true}) 
                .find('body', {log:true})
                .then(body => {
                    const stripeField = body.find(fieldSelector)
                    if (!stripeField.length) {
                        return getStripeField({iframeSelector, fieldSelector}, ++attempts)
                                  
                    } else 
                        return cy.wrap(stripeField)
                })
        }

getStripeField({
            iframeSelector: 'iframe[title="Secure card payment input frame"]', 
            fieldSelector: 'input[name=cardnumber]'
        })
            .type(orgData.cardNumber + orgData.cardExpiry + orgData.cardCVC + orgData.cardPostal)
```

The moment this line execute:

`.its('0.contentDocument', {log:true})`

the test timed out because it can't detect the document inside the iframe

`Timed out retrying after 30000ms: cy.its() errored because the property: 0.contentDocument does not exist on your subject.`

I've tried disabling the chrome security, it still doesn't work

`'chromeWebSecurity': false`

I've tried this plugin
https://github.com/dbalatero/cypress-plugin-stripe-elements#readme

```
cy.get('iframe[title="Secure card payment input frame"]').within(() => {
      cy.fillElementsInput('input[name=cardnumber]', '4242424242424242');
});
```

It still doesn't work

I've tried change the line to

`.its('0.contentWindow.window.document', {log:true})` 
It still timed out

I've tried this method

[Cypress with stripe: elements height not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902643/cypress-with-stripe-elements-height-not-loaded)
and it return error:

`Blocked a frame with origin *url* from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: It looks like there are different iframe selectors. First thing is to see what `<iframe>` you have on the page by running `cy.get('iframe').then(iframes => console.log(iframes))`.

Comment: Also, if you can post which Stripe API your page uses, would be helpful.

Comment: There are multiple iframe in the page, however I use 'iframe[title="Secure card payment input frame"]' for the selector and it return 1, the one that i need. For API I don't think i can

Answer (score 1):

If you think you have the right `iframeSelector`, and as you say it's failing on the `.its('0.contentDocument')` line, you could try moving the recursion point up to that line.

```js
function getStripeField({iframeSelector, fieldSelector}, attempts = 0) {
  Cypress.log({displayName: 'getCardField', message: `${fieldSelector}: ${attempts}`})

  if (attempts > 50) throw new Error('too many attempts')

  return cy.get(iframeSelector, {timeout:10_000})

    .then(iframes => {
      console.log('Number of iframes selected: ', iframes.length)
    })
    .eq(0)

    // failing on document, so add an extra recursion point here
    .then(iframe => {
      const document = iframe[0].contentDocument
      if (!document) {
        cy.wait(300)
          .then(() => {
            getStripeField({iframeSelector, fieldSelector}, ++attempts)
          })
      }
      return document
    })

    .find('body')
    .then(body => {
      const stripeField = body.find(fieldSelector)
      if (!stripeField.length) {
        return cy.wait(300)
          .then(() => {
            getStripeField({iframeSelector, fieldSelector}, ++attempts)
          })
      } else {
        return cy.wrap(stripeField)
      }
    })
}
```

If still no luck, you can add console.log into the new section above to examine what you get for `iframe` and `document`.

Also try bumping up `if (attempts > 50)` in case it's particularly slow to load the iframe document.

Also, maybe there are multiple iframes with that selector. I added an extra logging step so you can check that. If more than 1 iframe, you can try each in turn by changing `.eq(0)` to `.eq(1)`, `.eq(2)`, etc.

Comment: I've tried the recursion for getting the document part, even after bumping it up to 300 tries, it returns 'too many attempt'. By using the 'iframe[title="Secure card payment input frame"]' selector, it return only 1 iframe, the targeted one, so it return error when I bump up the 'eq(0)'

Comment: Also I put a log for 'iframe' and 'document'. The 'iframe' return 1 result, the right one. The 'document' return null.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I also tried some experiments with v3 API (guessing you might be using that), but haven't had consistent success yet. I think the key is to put retries in the correct places.